# Flex Layout content not showing accurately

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I'm trying to show 100% of content when screen size is extra small(xs). but it is not working.

```
<ng-template #chatlistwithwindow>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
      <app-chat-user-list fxFlex.xs="100%" fxFlex.gt-xs="23%" fxFlexFill></app-chat-user-list>
      <app-chat-window fxFlex.xs="100%" fxFlex.gt-xs="77%" fxFlexFill *ngIf="toShow" (closeChatWindow)="setToShow(toShow)"></app-chat-window>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Expected result should be 100% of  and  when screen size is extra small.  is show when user is selected from .

Image showing problem in alignment of content:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm not quite sure if I understood your question correctly. Please add more details if I got you wrong.*

My understanding of your issue: You want to

- show one element width 100% width, while hiding the other element when the screen size is XS
- show one element width 23% width and the other with the remaining width when the screen is greater than XS

You may achieve this using the following snippet:

```
<div class="content" fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex fxFlex.gt-xs="23%" class="side">XS: 23%, 100% else</div>
  <div fxFlex fxHide.xs="true" class="main">MAIN</div>
</div>
```

Find a live example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dhkyx

Comment: Going good, but both should occupy hundred, it is ok, but show which ever is open not with class side only. It is helpful with modification.